# How to solve Nginx WebSocket secure (wss) "error 426 Upgrade Required"?

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot, websocket

I tried to configure a Websocket proxy on my Nginx server, but unfortunately, I don't get it working. I have read various post here but I cannot get the server work. I think it has something to do between the client connection to the server. Local om my pc is everything working fine

client code:

```
 var port = new osc.WebSocketPort({
          url: "wss://circusfamilyprojects.nl/"
        });
```

server code:

```
var wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 8083
});
```

This is my configuration on Ngnix:

```
# custom code for hop by hop headers
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }


    #custom code for connection with websocket this is the port on the server
     upstream websocket  {
        server 178.62.209.37:8083;
    }

server {

      listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
      listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/circusfamilyprojects.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Cert$
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/circusfamilyprojects.nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Ce$
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

       root /var/www/html/vue/cfdomotica/server/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

       server_name  circusfamilyprojects.nl www.circusfmailyprojects.nl; # managed by Certbot

      location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.circusfamilyprojects.nl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = circusfamilyprojects.nl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 8080 ;
        listen [::]:8080 ;
    server_name  circusfamilyprojects.nl;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

In my browser I get the message "Status Code: 426 Upgrade Required" I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self by separating a server block for port 443 and a server block for the WebSocket client. I did the server block for the client on port 8086.